# Put linebreak between components rendered with .map and boostrap

Tags: reactjs

I´m rendering an array, every element of the array is showed with component "Post", but the elements are in the same line, I tried with

```
return (
    <div style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 65px)' }} className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        {posts.map((post) => {
            return <Post key={post._id} post={post} />
        })}
    </div>
);
```

The component "Post" is the next:
I´m using Boostrap por the css styles
return (

 {usuario.nombre} 

Special title treatment
{texto}

Go somewhere

 2 days ago 

);

My result (All the elements are in horizontal position and I need them in vertical position):
[image]

The father component  is root.
If I delete the css classes of the component "Post", teh problem remains.

Comment: Change your CSS? In isolation it's impossible to know why they're displaying the way they are.

Comment: Given just the code there, they *should* be rendering on different lines. Some of your CSS rules must be the problem. Can you post the CSS, and the parent DOM of the posts?

Comment: What's the CSS attached to the className `card` (that's on your outermost `<div>` in `Post`)

Comment: You can add codesandbox example from which we can deduce more.

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t say, I´m using boostrap

Comment: I think the class `d-flex` only does `display:flex`, and the default for that is `row`, you need to add another class to make it column. I think it's `flex-column`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this.

```
return (
    <div>
        {posts.map((post) => {
            return <><Post key={post._id} post={post} /><br /></>
        })}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: I tried, but it didn´t work, I did the same inside the component Post but it didn´t work either

Answer (score 0):

I only changed the class of div where I put the .map ;| adn the problem was solved.
`className="container"` instead `className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">`